# Null property value from Abstract class

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I would really appreciate any help with the following scenario that I'm working on and wasn't able to find a solution for. My apologies if the title does not match up with the current lingo too.

The following code is an example that I'm working:

```
public class SumObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected SumObject SumProperty { get; private set; }

    protected AbstractClass()
    {
        SetupSumObjecInAbstractClass();
        DoWorkInChildClass();
    }

    protected void SetupSumObjecInAbstractClass()
    {
        SumProperty = new SumObject() { ID = 1, Name = "James Dean" };
    }

    protected abstract void DoWorkInChildClass();
}

public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void DoWorkInChildClass()
    {
        if (SumProperty == null)
            throw new Exception("Dang!");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("My Name is: {0}"
                                        , SumProperty.Name));
    }
}
```

So, in this example, when the `ChildClass` is instantiated [`var name = new ChildClass();`] the `AbstractClass` sets up the property containing `SumObject` and then calls the `DoWorkInChildClass()` in its constructor. However, what I'm finding is that the property is null when the code in the `ChildClass` is executed and throws the exception.

So, does anybody know how to make the `SumProperty` available in the `ChildClass` and enable it to return the SumObject that was setup in the constructor of the `AbstractClass`?

I've seen this done before but I'm fuzzy on how it was done exactly.

Thanks again guys!

Comment: Actually, when I run your code and instantiate `ChildClass`, it displays "My Name is: James Dean". No exception, the property's not `null` for me (and I don't see any reason why it should be).

Comment: Thanks O. R. Mapper. Your response got me thinking to recheck the code. I discovered that a had created a property in the `ChildClass` having the same name as `SumProperty`. By removing it, the code executes correctly as intended.

Comment: As your problem seems to have been solved (or rather, it did not even exist in the first place), I suggest you delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copy your code to run and it works well.

```
public class SumObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected SumObject SumProperty { get; private set; }

    protected AbstractClass()
    {
        SetupSumObjecInAbstractClass();
        DoWorkInChildClass();
    }

    protected void SetupSumObjecInAbstractClass()
    {
        SumProperty = new SumObject() { ID = 1, Name = "James Dean" };
    }

    protected abstract void DoWorkInChildClass();
}

public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void DoWorkInChildClass()
    {
        if (SumProperty == null)
            throw new Exception("Dang!");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("My Name is: {0}"
                                        , SumProperty.Name));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var name = new ChildClass();
    }
}
```

My Name is: James Dean

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question?

Comment: @Robert, Actually, it was a silly error on my side. I had a property of the same name in the `ChildClass` as that can be found in the `AbstractClass`. I've flagged the question to be deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will help (please notice that I removed the abstract method you used):

```
public class SumObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

    public abstract class AbstractClass
    {
        protected SumObject SumProperty { get; private set; }

        protected AbstractClass()
        {
            SetupSumObjecInAbstractClass();
        }

        protected void SetupSumObjecInAbstractClass()
        {
            SumProperty = new SumObject() { ID = 1, Name = "James Dean" };
        }
    }


    public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
    {
        public ChildClass() : base()
        {
             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("My Name is: {0}"
                                            , SumProperty.Name));
        }
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yakiros, but it is not really what I want as I've got a lot of `ChildClass`s which will each have specific work done in the abstracted method.